# Brightness control Ubuntu Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, brightness, backlight

I am using a Thinkbook Gen 2 Laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS freshly installed.

I bumped into the same problem as many other people: the brightness of the screen doesn't change neither with the keyboard keys nor with the brightness slider, and this is certainly related to the NVIDIA GPU in the laptop.
For now no solution from different forums worked for me, and it starts to drive me crazy.

Nevertheless I want to share an interesting observation: under /sys/class/backlight I can find 2 directories: amdgpu_bl0 and nvidia_0. When I change the brightness with the keyboard or the slider, the brightness file in nvidia_0 changes its content accordingly, only this has no influence on the hardware. Instead, when I change the brightness in amdgpu_bl0 manually, the brightness of my screen does change!

Any thoughts or ideas about this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my Legion 5 with the Nvidia GPU (Ubuntu 22.04, now kernel 6.5.0-1008-oem & nvidia-driver-535).
It looks like it has been issue for years. :(

I have a small workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 == 1 ]; do
    cat /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness > /sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness
    inotifywait -s /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
done
```

You can run it as root, on system startup, or manually with sudo, then the values in both files will be synchronized, and brightness setting works as expected...

But I would be very happy, if the issue is resolved some day.